# Count sum of different rows and save in a single row BigQuery

Tags: mysql, google-bigquery

I am doing the data cleaning in a BigQuery. I managed to count each of the variables. However there are some redundant info with different variables, so I need to merge the number and save the overall total in a single row.

This is my work:

```
SELECT 
    day, 
    COUNT(*) as Total,
FROM
    table
where day<> 'null'
GROUP BY day
-- HAVING COUNT(*) >= 10?
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

The result is

[image]

What should I add so the Monday and Mndy is added in a single row? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN day in ('Monday', 'Mndy') THEN 'Monday' ELSE day END day, 
    COUNT(*) as Total,
FROM
    table
where day<> 'null'
GROUP BY 1
-- HAVING COUNT(*) >= 10?
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

Comment: can i just add CASE WHEN for the second variable? like for example for "Sunday" and "Sun"?